# Runtime error in using wordnet through JWNL, error in the props file

Tags: java, wordnet

hey i've tried this in netbeans but it won't work it gives me the same error no matter what i do!  can anyone help?

---

```
JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file_properties.xml"));

wordnet = Dictionary.getInstance();
IndexWord word = wordnet.getIndexWord(POS.VERB,"run");
Synset[] senses = word.getSenses();
for (int i = 0; i < senses.length; i++) 
{
   System.out.println(word + ": " + senses[i].getGloss());
}
```

---

and getting missing file exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:169)
    at testss.Testss.main(Testss.java:43)
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.install(FileBackedDictionary.java:111)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:32)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Could not create a file manager of type class net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:98)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:32)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\dict\index.adv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.openFile(PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.java:76)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.AbstractDictionaryFile.open(AbstractDictionaryFile.java:58)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalog.open(DictionaryCatalog.java:45)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalogSet.open(DictionaryCatalogSet.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.<init>(FileManagerImpl.java:71)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:96)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Wordnet db version being used in jwnlProperties.xml

```
<version publisher="Princeton" number="3" language="en"/>
```

File names in db have changed over versions, and JWNL supports them.

This should solve your problem, discussed in other places as well.
http://sourceforge.net/p/jwordnet/discussion/106153/thread/5ccfc039/

Answer (score 0):

Same issues was faced by me. And i solved it adding some missing files in **dict** folder.

```
     net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary   

    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:157)   at getHypernyms.main(getHypernyms.java:27) 
        Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: The properties file must specify a dictionary path    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:34)   at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary.install(FileBackedDictionary.java:100)   at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:32)    ... 2 more Caused by: net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Could not create a file manager of type class 

net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile  at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:71)  at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.AbstractValueParam.create(AbstractValueParam.java:32)   ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\WordNet\WordNet-2.0\dict\adj.dat 

(The system cannot find the file specified)     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)   at net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.openFile(PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile.java:76)     at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.AbstractDictionaryFile.open(AbstractDictionaryFile.java:58)  at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalog.open(DictionaryCatalog.java:46)    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file.DictionaryCatalogSet.open(DictionaryCatalogSet.java:34)  at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.<init>(FileManagerImpl.java:54)  at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl.create(FileManagerImpl.java:69)  ... 5 more
```

And i just copied the existing files and rename it to desired name. And re-run the program and it work perfectly. Missing Files are **adj.dat**, **noun.dat**, **adj.dat** and **.idx** etc. 
Example: Existing file name is **data.verb** ==> copy and paste it and rename it **verb.dat**, same with other files. and for **index.adj** rename to **adj.idx**.
For any query u can ping me. **anysocialmedia/nabilraza456**

Here is the output
[image]